# Sometimes vim doesn't expand foldings on horizontal movement

Tags: vim, macvim, folding, vim-plugin

I am experiencing a weird problem: vim doesn't expand my foldings sometimes when I use a horizontal gesture like `l`. It always expands if I use `zo` though. I can see `hor` option in my `foldopen` settings variable. I am experiencing this when `foldmethod` is set either to `indent` or `expr`. What may I be missing? I don't seem to be mapping `l` anywhere.

Thanks

Comment: Did you identify a pattern? A situation where it's more likely to happen?

Comment: It seems like this just happens randomly, I couldn't identify a pattern. There are methods where this happens more often, but they don't look different from other. I use expr and just check the first symbol of the line, really simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you cursor is on an empty line inside the fold then the left move (`l`) will not work, thus it won't open the fold.

The same happens if your cursor is at the last column in the line. But in this case an `h` will make the fold open.

You can check if the a movement command fails by paying attention to the error beep, the same it issues when you hit `Esc` when you are in normal mode. If you are unable to hear it, you could try using the `'visualbell'` option.

Comment: Thanks! That indeed was a problem.

Comment: Alternatively, you can `:set whichwrap+=h,l`, which makes these commands move across lines, too; but be aware that this is non-standard behavior.

Comment: Wow.  This was really bugging me.  It makes sense now, but it's very strange that vim will always show the cursor being at the very first position of a folder line, which makes me think it must be at the same position of the real unfolded text.  Not the case.  You have to think of the cursor position as it the text were always unfolded.